# Paperclip can't find imagemagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, homebrew

Okay, I have imagemagick installed on my local machine via homebrew, and Gemfile.lock shows paperclip locked at version `paperclip (3.0.4)`.

Per the setup instructions, I set the following command in development.rb

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

Which lines up with what the terminal says

```
$ which identify
  # => /usr/local/bin/identify
```

However, when I try to upload an image, the following error spits out on my form

```
/var/folders/dm/lnshrsls2zz6l4r_tkbk7j2w0000gn/T/avatar20120522-44111-gfis2q.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

Which every SO question I can find on the matter suggests the problem is Paperclip can't find identify in it's command path.

I used the Paperclip generator to add the avatar to my database, and my model has:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
```

Furthermore, if I load up `rails c` and look at Paperclip.options, I can see the command path has been properly set in the hash.

Not quite sure what to do at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does the identify command actually run from the command prompt? e.g. $ identify -version

Comment: It returns `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtiff.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5`

Comment: Do you know if you have `/usr/local/lib` included for your ld.so conf? if your running Ubuntu (and probably other Linux dists) you should make sure `/usr/local/lib` is in some file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` (default the `libc` seams to include it, if I haven't added it manually, dont remember). Then run `ldconfig` as root and restart the web server.

Comment: Running OS X, as near as I can tell, ld.so.conf isn't a thing over here.

Comment: Ah ok. Does `/usr/local/lib/libtiff.3.dylib` really exist? have you fiddled with any DYLD_* environment variables? (check `man dydl`, `/usr/local/lib` is included in the default fallback search paths).

Comment: You can use `otool -L /usr/local/bin/identify` if you want to see what libraries the binary is using.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I uninstalled, updated homebrew and reinstalled and now everything works. Thanks guys

Comment: Good. If you figure out what the real problem was please answer your own question so others can be helped. My guess is that the libtiff was missing as OSX seams to already try to load from /usr/local/lib

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm glad that running the command got you started on the right path.

The problem was that your ImageMagick was compiled for the wrong architecture:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtiff.3.dylib Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify Reason: image not found Trace/BPT trap
```

Uninstalling imagemagick, updating homebrew and reinstalling it was the right thing to do.

Comment: For me `brew update && brew upgrade imagemagick` did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case, I made it work with this trick:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/3.9.5/lib/libtiff.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtiff.3.dylib
```

And is working like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what the exact problem was, however I uninstalled Image Magick, updated Homebrew and reinstalled imagemagick and now everything is working.